# why I get "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" error when I compile a cURL lib code?

Tags: c, macos, curl

I try to activate cURL lib on my mac, then I want to check if it works or not...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

 int main(void)
 {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl)
    {
       curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://google.com");
       /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */
       curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

       /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
       res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
       /* Check for errors */
       if(res != CURLE_OK)
       fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
       curl_easy_strerror(res));

       /* always cleanup */
       curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
  return 0;
 }
```

but i get an error when I compile it...
"linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"
i'd be grateful if somebody can help to fix it... cause I'm kinda beginner and it's my first experience with mac and cURL library...

Comment: please post the real/full linker error message.

Comment: Did you link the curl lib? Post your gcc command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking curl library problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20192415/linking-curl-library-problems)

Comment: Makefiles can possibly solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56047948/compiling-and-linking-curl-easy-interface-with-c/56049124#56049124

Answer (score 0):

Try linking `libcurl` library in `CMakeLists.txt`.

Helped me:

```
include_directories(/usr/local/opt/curl/include/curl)
target_link_libraries(ProkectName "/usr/local/opt/curl/include/curl/curl.h")
```