# Compiling and Linking curl easy interface with C++

Tags: c++, http, curl

**Context**

Attempting to run this [curl_easy_init - Start a libcurl easy session](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_init.html) in my C++ program. The curl library has a large selection of APIs including [simple post](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simplepost.html) and many others for, but I'm stuck on getting my compiling and linking step configured correctly. I looked to the [curl websites tutorial](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html) for guidance on compiling and linking this library to my program, but still still facing this error.

*curl is located here*

```
ᴾᴋᴹɴ Master Red ▰ ◓ ◓ ◓ ◓ ◓ ◓ 

> curl-config --cflags
-I/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.64.1/include
```

*curl libraries include*

```
ᴾᴋᴹɴ Master Red ▰ ◓ ◓ ◓ ◓ ◓ ◓ 

> curl-config --libs
-L/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.64.1/lib -lcurl -lldap -lz
```

*Even after adding to my include path, still get the same error.*

```
# c++ curl support for the g++ compiler
# curl-config --cflags
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.64.1/include:${CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH}"
# curl-config --libs which include -lcurl -lldap -lz
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.64.1/lib:${CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH}"
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
```

---

**Error**

```
ᴾᴋᴹɴ Master Red ▰ ◓ ◓ ◓ ◓ ◓ ◓ 

> g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp && ./a.out
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_curl_easy_cleanup", referenced from:
      _main in main-9d2f7a.o
  "_curl_easy_init", referenced from:
      _main in main-9d2f7a.o
  "_curl_easy_perform", referenced from:
      _main in main-9d2f7a.o
  "_curl_easy_setopt", referenced from:
      _main in main-9d2f7a.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

---

**Source**

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        CURLcode res;
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
}
```

Comment: `curl-config --cflags` and `curl-config --libs` gives you the flags you need to provide to the compiler and linker (respectively) when building with the cURL library. You do not use any of those flags when building your application.

Comment: `g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp curl-config --cflags curl-config --libs` so I should call this when building with `g++`? This raises unsupported option and no such file error s

Comment: I add these to my `~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: Rather than cluttering up your .bash_profile, I'd recommend creating a makefile, and set up your specific -I and -L paths there.

Comment: Thanks I will do this `g++ Main.cpp -I/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.64.1/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.64.1/lib -lcurl -lldap -lz && ./a.out` this appears to work. I should be okay to write and compile my program in `c++`? It appears this API works with both languages.

Comment: @user888379 I've added an example makefile let me know what you think

Comment: Simply run `g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp $(curl-config --cflags) $(curl-config --libs)`

Answer (score 0):

Use a makefile instead call `make` on the command line and you're good to go

```
# *****************************************************
# Variables to control Makefile operation

CXX = g++

# ****************************************************
# Targets needed to bring the executable up to date

main: main.cpp
    $(CXX) main.cpp -I/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.64.1/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.64.1/lib -lcurl -lldap -lz && ./a.out
```

Comment: Looks pretty good. One problem is that your command doesn't produce 'main', it produces 'a.out'. I would change it to something like "$(CXX) main.cpp -I/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.64.1/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.64.1/lib -lcurl -lldap -lz -o main" and remove the "&& a.out". make is very powerful. Once you start getting more comfortable with it, your command can become more like: "$(CXX) $^ -I/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.64.1/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.64.1/lib -lcurl -lldap -lz -o $@". Have fun!